# ValueError when trying to write data to xlsx sheet using Openpyxl

Tags: python, arrays, web-scraping, openpyxl, xlsx

I'm trying to save the outputted social media link to an excel file using openpyxl but getting the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxx/_Main_.py", line 40, in <module>
    sheet.cell(cell.row, col2).value = ig_get_present
  File "/Users/xxxx/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 215, in value
    self._bind_value(value)
  File "/Users/xxxx/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 184, in _bind_value
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert ['https://www.instagram.com/xxxx/'] to Excel
```

This is the code leading to it, no idea why its happening.

```py
column_name = 'URL'
column_name2 = 'Instagram'

headers = [cell.value for cell in sheet[1]]

col = get_column_letter(headers.index(column_name) + 1)

col2 = headers.index(column_name2) + 1

for cell in sheet[col][1:]:
    url = cell.value
    r = requests.get(url)
    ig_get = ['instagram.com']
    ig_get_present = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    all_links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
    for ig_get in ig_get:
        for link in all_links:
            if ig_get in link.attrs['href']:
                ig_get_present.append(link.attrs['href'])
    sheet.cell(cell.row, col2).value = ig_get_present
```

Comment: don't use the same variable name for the items you are iterating through and the list `for ig_get in ig_get:`

Comment: Check the data type of `ig_get_present`. You probably want to convert it to a string. Openpyxl doesn't know and also doesn't try guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the data to a string fixed my issue.

```py
ig_got = str(ig_get_present)
sheet.cell(cell.row, col2).value = ig_got
```